FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy GH Action returns invalid details_url
The problem I have is with the details_url stored as Action summary. Here's my workflow:
name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge
'on':
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - run: npm ci && npm run build
      - id: deploy
        uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: '${{ **** }}'
          firebaseServiceAccount: '${{ **** }}'
          channelId: live
          projectId: ****
      - name: Set step summary
        run: echo '[Deploy URL](${{ steps.deploy.outputs.details_url }})' >> $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY

Now, the last part, echo '[Deploy URL](${{ steps.deploy.outputs.details_url }})' >> $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY, adds a nice link for me to follow and see the live app.
The thing is, I get the link to GitHub action run instead, like:
https://github.com/****/****/actions/runs/107****

The odd thing is: I have similar worflow with exactly same step for on-demand Preview deploy. And it is working just fine.
    - name: Set step summary
      run: echo '[Preview URL](${{ steps.deploy.outputs.details_url }})' >> $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY

The only difference I can think would matter is that instead channelId: live there is a predefined desired url built with pr id, etc. A per the docs this deploys correctly to live channel of my default hosting site.
details_url shouls as per docs return the url the code was deployed to... Why on earth do I get GitHub Action run?!
